# Корректное использование json_encode

Tags: php

есть следующий метод :

```php
  public function readJson()
        {
            $this->connect();
            $contentJson = fread($this->file, filesize($this->fileName));
            $this->disconnect();
            return $contentJson;
        }
```

Вопрос как корректно применить к данному методу функцию json_encode()?

Comment: Опишите проблему подробнее и то чего выхотите добиться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на самом деле вопрос не до конца понятен. я, вот, полагаю, что вы хотите полученные из файла данные передать в json_encode, тогда:

```
public function readJson()
{
    $this->connect();
    $contentJson = fread($this->file, filesize($this->fileName));
    $this->disconnect();
    return json_encode($contentJson);
}
```